# Linq .Select with foreach

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I need some help in a .Net conversion from a System.Linq methods into a non Linq version.

For Funktion Select():

```
 private readonly Dictionary<int, string> _foobarKeys = new Dictionary<int, string>();

 public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, object>> GetFoobarator()
        {
            return _foobarKeys.Values
                               .Select(k => new KeyValuePair<string, object>(k, _dict[k]))
                               .GetFoobarator();
        }
```

Same Problem is with the functions Max():

```
var maxKeyIndex = _foobarKeys.Keys.Max();
```

... Any():

```
_foobarKeys.Any(kv => kv.Value == key)
```

and FirstOrDefault():

```
 private readonly Dictionary<string, object> _bar = new Dictionary<string, object>();
public bool Remove(string key)
        {
            var fooIndex = _foobarKeys.FirstOrDefault(kv => kv.Value == key)
                                       .Key;

            _foobarKeys.Remove(fooIndex);
            return _bar.Remove(key);
        }
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why do you need this?  Are you porting to an older version of the .NET Framework that doesn't support LINQ?  If so, what version?

Comment: You could check out Jon Skeet's [Edulinq](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/category/edulinq/).  It shows how to implement all the linq methods.

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0):

What is the problem of using the built-in LINQ extension methods?

Anyway, here are possible implementations:

---

#### Select

> Projects each element of a sequence into a new form.

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> sequence, Func<TSource, TResult> selector)
{
    if (sequence == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("sequence");
    if (selector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("selector");
    foreach (TSource element in sequence)
       yield return selector(element);
}
```

#### Max

> Returns the maximum value in a generic sequence.

```
public static TSource Max<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> sequence)
{
    if (sequence == null) throw new ArgumentNullException();
    Comparer<TSource> comparer = Comparer<TSource>.Default;
    TSource value = default(TSource);
    if (value == null)
    {
        foreach (TSource elem in sequence)
             if (elem != null && (elem == null || comparer.Compare(elem, value) > 0))
                   value = elem;
        return value;
    }
    else
    {
        bool hasValue = false;
        foreach (TSource elem in sequence)
        {
            if (hasValue)
            {
                if (comparer.Compare(elem, value) > 0)
                   value = elem;
            }
            else
            {
                    value = elem;
                    hasValue = true;
            }
        }

        if (!hasValue) // No elements in sequence
            throw new InvalidOperationException();

        return value;
    }
}
```

#### Any

> Determines whether any element of a sequence satisfies a condition.

```
public static bool Any<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> sequence, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    if (sequence == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("sequence");
    if (predicate == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("predicate");
    foreach (TSource elem in sequence)
       if (predicate(elem))
          return true;
    return false;
}
```

#### FirstOrDefault

> Returns the first element of the sequence that satisfies a condition or a default value if no such element is found.

```
 public static TSource FirstOrDefault<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> sequence, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
 {
     if (sequence == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("sequence");
     if (predicate == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("predicate");
     foreach (TSource elem in sequence)
         if (predicate(elem))
             return elem;
     return default(TSource);
 }
```